# Installing `numpy` within a virtualenv in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python, numpy, package, virtualenv, pip

I got the following exceptions when install `numpy` using `easy_install numpy`, could somebody help please? Whether I am using `pip` or `easy_install`, I got the same problems. It is hard to understand what's going wrong.

```
non-existing path in 'numpy/core': 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/multiarray'
non-existing path in 'numpy/core': 'build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/umath'
numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:2549:1: warning: ‘longlong_arrtype_hash’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c:74:1: warning: ‘_array_ass_item’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:226:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
numpy/core/src/multiarray/scalartypes.c.src:2549:1: warning: ‘longlong_arrtype_hash’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c:74:1: warning: ‘_array_ass_item’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
build/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy/__ufunc_api.h:226:1: warning: ‘_import_umath’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.6/README.Bugs> for instructions.
error: Setup script exited with error: Command "gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/private -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/multiarray -Ibuild/src.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/umath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule_onefile.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/numpy/core/src/multiarray/multiarraymodule_onefile.o" failed with exit status 4
/tmp/easy_install-l43x51/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:252: RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'numpy.distutils' not found while handling absolute import
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-l43x51/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 252, in clean_up_temporary_directory
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-l43x51/numpy-1.6.1/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py", line 252, in clean_up_temporary_directory
ImportError: No module named numpy.distutils
```

Comment: I think `gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)` is the key point. Looks like you need to file a bug report.

Comment: I just do a `apt-get upgrade gcc` and everything works now. Thanks.

Comment: @hilau can you add that to the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps the GCC is not updated. I just did a `apt-get upgrade gcc` and `numpy` compiled successfully.

Comment: What version of gcc did you end up with? I have gcc 4.6.3 and am still seeing the error.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to use this command instead of easy_install. Worked for me

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy python-scipy
```

Comment: Thanks. I usually install packages inside `virtualenv` so I don't pollute the global namespaces when developing several projects. Prefer `easy_install`.

Comment: `apt-get install` does not install the package within the virtualenv. I do not want to pollute global environment.

Comment: -1 for suggesting an answer which is not in line with the question related to virtualenv whose purpose is to manage different virsions of packages separated from global (system) packages.